# React - Updating state (array of objects). Do I need to deep copy the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following `state`:

```
const[images,setImages] = useState([
  {src: 'stringSRC1', selected: false},
  {src: 'stringSRC2', selected: false},
  {src: 'stringSRC3', selected: false}
]);
```

I'm updating it (toggling selected state) with this code:

```
function handleImageClick(index) {
  props.setImages((prevState)=>{
    const aux = Array.from(prevState);
    aux[index].selected = !aux[index].selected;
    return aux;
  });
}
```

It works as intended. But I've thought of one thing.

When I'm copying the array from `prevState`, **I'm creating a new array, but the objects (stored as references) will remain the same.** I've tested and they do not change when you copy the array like that.

**QUESTION**

Is this a bad practice? Should I bother to deep copy the array, as in create a new array and create brand new objects? Or this is just fine?

Comment: FYI, the [answer you've currently accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56296211/157247) is incorrect, details [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey T.J, thanks for your comment. Why is it incorrect? Take a look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-danilo-61o4d?file=/src/App.tsx) that I made using `produce` from `immer`. The immutable update changes the array reference and every item that has been modified, but it does not change the reference for the items that were not touched by the update. Isn't `produce` used frequently to perform immutable React state updates? I wouldn't go as far and say that the content of the array does not matter, but I guess you don't have to deep clone it. Do you agree?

Comment: [The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) is clear that you cannot directly modify state items. If you do, they may not re-render, including (but not limited to, I don't think) cases where components avoid re-rendering if their props don't change (via `React.memo`, `PureComponent`, or `shouldComponentUpdate`).

Comment: I haven't used immer, but from the documentation and a quick check, it looks like [`produce`](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce/) creates the new object for you, so you're not breaking the rule there. (If I save `prevState[1]` to a local, then compare it with `nextState[1]` after the `produce` call, it's a different object -- which is what the docs say you need, so all good.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You linked to documentation about class based `setState` which is different from the `useState` hook and different rules apply. Shallow copies of datastructure used with the `useState` hook are completely fine as long as you do not use those nested instances in dependency arrays or as props for `memo`'d components.

Comment: @Martin - I don't think that part of it is specific to class components, but you're right the context around it is the older class syntax. Please provide a citation for "it's completely fine." Re your "unless," that's a **heck** of a caveat. :-) And if it's true (with that caveat) for function components, why wouldn't it be true (with that caveat) for class components? What's different? State is state.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The only requirement for function based state updates (`useState`) to trigger a rerender is to create a fresh object for the state itself. Yes, the React documentation recommends to always deep clone nested data structures to avoid potential bugs that would arise if you need to rely on changing object identities somewhere. As I have mentioned this is the case with components wrapped with `memo` or dependency arrays like in `useEffect(some, [foo.nestedObject])`. I don't deep clone as long as I don't have to. That's all I say. But when the need arises, then I deep clone.

Comment: @Martin - It's fine if you want to write code that contradicts what the docs tell you, knowing as it were the risks, but promoting to others that it's *correct* to do so isn't doing anyone a positive service. Again, do you have a citation? And for it being different for function vs. class comps? Not least because React is complicated and adding more complicated features? Separately, I'd expect most significant components to optimize against re-rendering, which breaks if you directly modify objects (as in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/deep-vs-shallow-updates-c0rx3?file=/src/App.js)).

Comment: React team is writing the docs for functional-based react and there is a section that briefly touches upon the same issue. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#making-other-changes-to-an-array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is how it's supposed to work. Yeap, the objects are not changing, but the important here is that the array changes. React performs shallow comparations between the DOM and the virtual DOM to now when things changed. Once your new array is compared with the old one the change will be detected, the content of the array itself doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - You still need to make deep copies.

The [official docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state) recommend making deep copies:

> State can hold any kind of JavaScript value, including objects. But you shouldn’t change objects that you hold in the React state directly. Instead, when you want to update an object, you need to create a new one (or make a copy of an existing one), and then set the state to use that copy.

They also suggest making your state objects as flat as possible to make deep copying easier and if that's not an option, using something like [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer) to handle the deep-copying for you.

> If your state is deeply nested, you might want to consider flattening it. But, if you don’t want to change your state structure, you might prefer a shortcut to nested spreads. Immer is a popular library that lets you write using the convenient but mutating syntax and takes care of producing the copies for you.

Comment: Hey @rangfu , I think the documentation is mainly talking about the top-level state object. Because even `immer` (which is definitely an official recomendation) won't deep copy everything. It will detect what's changed, and it will go up in the object tree recreating everything. But for example, it won't go sideways in the tree (e.g: siblings of the node that's changed are not recreated). Take a look at this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-danilo-61o4d?file=/src/App.tsx). So, IMO, it's 100% ok to not deep copy everything in an array of objects.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you must deep clone, if you want to avoid side effects.

In your function:

```
function handleImageClick(index) {
  props.setImages((prevState)=>{
    const aux = Array.from(prevState);
    aux[index].selected = !aux[index].selected;
    return aux;
  });
}
```

As you are using `Array.from` you are getting references to the objects stored, so your prevState is modified.

See this:

```
setTest(prevState => {
      console.log("PrevState", prevState);
      const b = Array.from(prevState);
      b[0].a = b[0].a + 1;
      return b;
    });
```

You can test it here:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/exciting-mcnulty-6spdh?fontsize=14

You will see that prevState has the next value, so you lose your prevState value.

Imagine that you want to do this in your code:

```
function handleImageClick(index) {
      props.setImages((prevState)=>{
        const aux = Array.from(prevState);
        aux[index].selected = !aux[index].selected;
        aux[index + 1].selected = prevState[index].selected;
        return aux;
      });
    }
```

`aux[index + 1].selected = prevState[index].selected;` is broken!!

So you need to deep copy the array to avoid this kind of things.

You can do: `const aux = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState));`

Comment: Thanks! I agree that if I want to access the object property that I have just changed, that information will be inaccessible and completely gone. But other than that, do you see any other issues? Because once that `setState()` completes running, the `prevState` object won't be available anymore anyway. On the next time, it will be a different object. I.E: My only worry should be about the `prevState` values during the execution of the current ongoing `setState()`?

Comment: Because if that's the only issue, I don't think it's worth to deep copy everything as a habit just for that possibility. I can save that specific property into an auxiliar variable just to access further down the code once I've changed it. What do you think? Is it worth to deep copy everything just for this specific kind of situation?