# JS spread operator workflow on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, spread

React suggests not to mutate state. I have an array of objects which I am manipulating based on some events. My question is, is it okay to write it like this:

```
const makeCopy = (arr) => arr.map((item) => ({ ...item }));

function SomeComponenet() {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState(aemFilterData);

    const handleFilterClick = (filter, c) => {
        let copiedFilters = makeCopy(filters);

        /**
         * Apply toggle on the parent as well
         */
        if (!("parentId" in filter)) {
            copiedFilters[filter.id].open = !copiedFilters[filter.id].open;
        }
        setFilters(copiedFilters);
    }
}
```

Am I mutating the original object by doing like above? Or does it make a difference if written like this:

```
const makeCopy = (arr) => arr.map((item) => ({ ...item }));

function SomeComponent() {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState(aemFilterData);

    const handleFilterClick = (filter, c) => {
        let copiedFilters = makeCopy(filters);

        /**
         * Apply toggle on the parent as well
         */
        if (!("parentId" in filter)) {
            copiedFilters = copiedFilters.map((f) => {
            if (filter.id === f.id) {
              return {
                ...f,
                open: !f.open,
              };
            } else {
              return { ...f };
            }
          });
        }
        setFilters(copiedFilters);
    }
}
```

What's the preferred way to do this? Spread operators are getting a lot verbose and I am not liking it, but I prefer it if that's how I need to do it here. immutable.js and immer or not an option right now.

Comment: Use JSON for deep copy --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47690512/12509535

Comment: map is enough to make copy, no need for copying every item

Comment: Would you still recommend the same for the not-so-nested array? Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/thomsebastin/ddbeb878d959cf614ce520a85d25d233

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI So is it safe to assume that the first way is okay?

Comment: The childIds array won't be cloned using spread operator and would be susceptible to changes from both objects as both would share the same...https://jsfiddle.net/aejgupLs/

Comment: @ThomasSebastian yes, 1st approach is enough. i put detailed answer below. Good luck!

Comment: @SiddharthS. Luckily, the "childIds" is read-only throughout the lifecycle of this component since there is no removal/reordering of children anywhere in the requirement. But deep cloning might help keep things clean, so it is indeed an option worth considering if things get out of hand.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian React does not require you to make a deep clone with the new `useState` hook. The only thing that needs to change when you update the state is the object identity of the state object itself. Because React only compares that with the previous one to decide if it must re-render. So a shallow `const newFilters = [...filters];` is enough for most use cases. However, if you take out inner parts of the state to feed a dependency array somewhere you would need a fresh identity: `useEffect(some, [filters[0]])` would require a fresh identity. Does this clear things up?

Comment: The old class rules for `setState()` don't apply for `useState()`.

Comment: @Martin So, as long as I am not using some nested item within the state object as a dependency, it won't be an issue? Is my understanding correct? Does this mean I can safely consider the first approach above?

Comment: `as long as I am not using some nested item within the state object as a dependency, it won't be an issue?` Yes, correct, it won't be an issue. `Is my understanding correct?` Seems to be the case. `Does this mean I can safely consider the first approach above?` Yes, actually your first approach is already an overkill. You even cloned all your items in the array. It would be enough to just clone the array, hence doing this `const copiedFilters = [...filters]` is sufficient. No need for your `makeCopy` function.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296041/react-updating-state-array-of-objects-do-i-need-to-deep-copy-the-array) is a question that covers your use-case. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const makeCopy = (arr) => arr.map((item) => item );
```

With above code, it's mutating on the original object reference because we're not creating a deep clone.

```js
copiedFilters[filter.id].open = !copiedFilters[filter.id].open;
```

Here reference of `copiedFilters[filter.id]` and `filters[filter.id]` is same.

With spread operator

```js
const makeCopy = (arr) => arr.map((item) => ({ ...item }));
```

Here we create a new copy of the inner object too. So `copiedFilters[filter.id]` and `filters[filter.id]` will have different reference.

This is same as your second approach.

So either you use spread operator while making a copy or you can skip making a copy in the second approach and directly map on `filters` since you're using spread operator there. This looks better because, why run loop twice - first to create copy and then to update `open`.

```js
// let copiedFilters = makeCopy(filters); Not needed in second approach
copiedFilters = copiedFilters.map((f) => {
  if (filter.id === f.id) {
    return {
      ...f,
      open: !f.open,
    };
  } else {
    return { ...f };
  }
});
```

You can create a deep clone when you copy but that would be waste of computation and memory, I don't think it's needed here.
Deep clone is helpful when you have further nesting in the object.

Comment: I think I will stick to the second approach based on your advice then; Considering, I have events in other places and don't want to deep clone everywhere if that is less performant.

Comment: My code is full of such map and spread operations. I was wondering if I could deep-clone and simply modify them directly. Will there be a huge impact on performance or is it an okay trade-off to make considering readability will improve a lot.

Comment: You'll have to measure the performance impact. In most cases you'll not see any difference but theoretically deepclone should be expensive. Libraries like ImmutableJS might do a better job at it though.

Comment: In your answer, you said the reference of `copiedFilters[filter.id] and filters[filter.id] is same`. Could you check this fiddle, because I noticed that they are different? Since there is no further nesting, I feel it works. https://jsfiddle.net/vcnd7woj/

Comment: @ThomasSebastian In the fiddle you're using spread operator but instead if you had `arr.map((item) => item );` then the ref would be same

Comment: My bad, in your code, in first approach you're using spread operator to it is creating new reference but if you go further deep in the object level, it'd be same references

Comment: @ThomasSebastian updated the answer

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your effort. I will keep things as is now. But good to have an understanding of all these gotchas. I'll probably end up using immer/immutable.js etc...