# React.useMemo is re-rendering all items in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I have a react component that stores a set of fruits in useState. I have a memoized function (visibleFruits) that filters fruits. I map visibleFruits to the dom.

The problem is, when i check a fruit, all visible fruits re-render.

I am expecting that only the selected one re-renders since it is the only one that is changing.

Is there a way for me to use this pattern but prevent all from re-rendering on check?

In real life, there is a complex function in visibleFruits useMemo. So I can't simply append the filter before the map.

Edit, here is updated edit:

```
const Example = () => {
    const [fruits, setFruits] = React.useState([
        { id: 1, name: 'apple', visible: true, selected: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'banana', visible: false, selected: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'orange', visible: true, selected: false }
    ])

    const visibleFruits = React.useMemo(() => {
        return fruits.filter((f) => f.visible)
    }, [fruits])

    const handleCheck = (bool, id) => {
        setFruits((prev) => {
            return prev.map((f) => {
                if (f.id === id) {
                    f.selected = bool
                }
                return f
            })
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {visibleFruits.map((fruit) => {
                return <FruitOption fruit={fruit} handleCheck={handleCheck} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

const FruitOption = ({ fruit, handleCheck }) => {
    console.log('** THIS RENDERS TWICE EVERY TIME USER SELECTS A FRUIT **')
    return (
        <div key={fruit.id}>
            <input
                checked={fruit.selected}
                onChange={(e) => handleCheck(e.target.checked, fruit.id)}
                type='checkbox'
            />
            <label>{fruit.name}</label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's a problem with the `handleCheck` function (but it's not related to what you're asking about). Your code is **modifying** a `fruit` object directly (`f.selected = bool`), but you're [not allowed to do that with React state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly), objects in state **must not** be directly modified, and rendering may not be correct if you break that rule. Instead, you need to copy the object and modify the copy (like you are with the array):

```
const handleCheck = (bool, id) => {
    setFruits((prev) => {
        return prev.map((f) => {
            if (f.id === id) {
                return {...f, selected: bool}; // ***
            }
            return f;
        });
    });
};
```

But that's not what you're asking about, just something else to fix. :-)

The reason you see the `console.log` executed twice after `handleCheck` is that the component has to be re-rendered (for the change), and there are two visible fruits, so you see two calls to your `FruitOption` component function. There are two reasons for this:

1. `handleChange` changes every time your `Example` component function is called, so `FruitOption` sees a new prop every time; and
2. `FruitOption` doesn't avoid re-rendering when its props don't change, so even once you've fixed #1, you'd still see two `console.log` calls; and

Separately, there's no [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) on the `FruitOption` elements, which can cause rendering issues. Always include a meaningful key when rendering elements in an array. (Don't just use the index, [it's problematic](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318); but your fruit objects have an `id`, which is perfect.)

To fix it:

1. Memoize `handleChange` so that it's not recreated every time, probably via [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), and
2. Use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) so that `FruitOption` doesn't get called if its props don't change (see the end of this answer for the `class` component equivalent), and
3. Add a meaningful [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to the `FruitOption` elements in `Example`

Taking those and the `handleChange` fix above and putting them all together:

```js
const Example = () => {
    const [fruits, setFruits] = React.useState([
        { id: 1, name: 'apple', visible: true, selected: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'banana', visible: false, selected: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'orange', visible: true, selected: false }
    ]);

    const visibleFruits = React.useMemo(() => {
        return fruits.filter((f) => f.visible);
    }, [fruits]);

    const handleCheck = React.useCallback(
        (bool, id) => {
            setFruits((prev) => {
                return prev.map((f) => {
                    if (f.id === id) {
                        return {...f, selected: bool}; // ***
                    }
                    return f;
                });
            });
        },
        []  // *** No dependencies since all it uses is `setFruits`, which is
            // stable for the lifetime of the component
    );

    return (
        <div>
            {visibleFruits.map((fruit) => {
                // *** Note the key
                return <FruitOption key={fruit.id} fruit={fruit} handleCheck={handleCheck} />
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

// *** `React.memo` will compare the props and skip the call if they're the same, reusing
// the previous call's result.
const FruitOption = React.memo(({ fruit, handleCheck }) => {
    console.log(`Rendering fruit ${fruit.id}`);
    return (
        <div key={fruit.id}>
            <input
                checked={fruit.selected}
                onChange={(e) => handleCheck(e.target.checked, fruit.id)}
                type='checkbox'
            />
            <label>{fruit.name}</label>
        </div>
    );
});

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

As you can see, with all that in place, only the changed fruit is re-rendered.

Re `React.memo`: For components with more complicated requirements, you can provide a function as a second argument that determines whether the two sets of props are "the same" for rendering purposes. By default, `React.memo` just does a shallow equality comparison, which is often sufficient.

---

Finally: For `class` components, the equivalent of `React.memo` without providing an equality callback is extending [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) instead of `Component`. If you want to make your check of the props more fine-grained, you can implement [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) instead.

Comment: Your information regarding not modifing state in-place does only apply for the old class based state. It does not hold true for `useState` hooks. This was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296041/react-updating-state-array-of-objects-do-i-need-to-deep-copy-the-array).

Comment: @Martin - The answer there saying you don't need to is incorrect.

Comment: @Martin , to prove tjCrowser is correct, you can see on his snippet in his answer that if you do not deep copy the fruit object , the checkbox is not checkable. You can try it yourself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wow ,  wrapping  components with React.memo  is what I've been missing now for a year or 2. Time to go back and refactor a s^&* load of code. Thanks so much this has been huge

Comment: @Jared - You're welcome! :-) (FWIW, the class component equivalents should you ever need them are `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate`.)

Comment: @Jared Well, the first version of your code did not utilize `memo`, your edited version does. That makes all the difference to the question whether you need to clone array items or not, because now object identity is relevant. Which wasn't the case in the first version.

Comment: @Jared - FWIW, Martin and I pick this up [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296041/react-updating-state-array-of-objects-do-i-need-to-deep-copy-the-array?noredirect=1#comment124299714_56296041). AFAIKT, Martin's basically saying you can *get away* with directly modifying objects in state, despite the docs saying not to, with some caveats. And maybe you can, but A) It's not correct as far as I can tell, and with React adding advanced features, I wouldn't guarantee it doesn't break things unexpectedly, and B) Doing so won't work with components that optimize re-rendering.